# UIImageView and UIWebView in UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have added UIImageView with view frame height and width and below that UIWebView has to be loaded. I am not sure how to implement this. I tried to add both in UIScrollView. Image is perfectly displaying but WebView not loaded. Adding UIWebView to UIScrollView is not good practice as its below screen, I need to make it in scroll. I am not using Storyboard, all through programming.

Please suggest what should be the best approach to implement this. Wether to use UIWebView in UIScrollView or if added then why it's not loaded. It comes blank.

```
func viewDidLoad(){

    var image = UIImage(frame: view.bounds)
    var webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:  self.view.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    var scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height*2)

    webView.delegate = self
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.google.com")))
    scrollView.addSubview(image)
    scrollView.addSubView(webView)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){

}
func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){

}
```

Thanks

Comment: why not you show the codes on how you add your views?

Comment: Like @koropok is saying, seeing code would help produce a better answer. We might have different suggestions if you're using nibs, storyboards, programmatic UIKit, or something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I tried to put relevant code. Please have a look.

Comment: what seems to be the problem? i've tried with your codes and it seems to be working. uiimageview on top and uiwebview below.

Comment: Is it? not at my end. Below UIImage, it's all blank..no webView.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.

**Please check if you are getting this error:**

App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

If you are getting this error, then add this in `info.plist` file:

[image]

Comment: App Transport Security issue not there..Application already communicating with database server thru API's.

Comment: Is the url that you want to display in webview working actually?